# ERROR: for nodejs unauthorized: access to the requested resource is not authorized

Tags: docker, sylius

I want to use sylius with docker

I followed the same steps of official website;

when I type the command "docker-compose pull --ignore-pull-failures || true", a have this error :

```
Pulling mysql   ... done
Pulling php     ... error
Pulling nodejs  ... error
Pulling nginx   ... error
Pulling mailhog ... done

ERROR: for nginx  unauthorized: access to the requested resource is not authorized

ERROR: for nodejs  unauthorized: access to the requested resource is not authorized

ERROR: for php  unauthorized: access to the requested resource is not authorized
ERROR: unauthorized: access to the requested resource is not authorized
unauthorized: access to the requested resource is not authorized
unauthorized: access to the requested resource is not authorized
```

help me SVP

Comment: Are you using this github project https://github.com/Sylius/Docker ? if so add to your question so people can help you

Comment: But this project github.com/Sylius/Docker has been abandoned ?  This project has been abandoned 

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work by removing the cache and image from the dockercompose.yml:

```
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      target: sylius_nginx
      cache_from:
        - quay.io/sylius/php:latest
        - quay.io/sylius/nodejs:latest
        - quay.io/sylius/nginx:latest
    image: quay.io/sylius/nginx:latest
    depends_on:
      - php
      - nodejs # to ensure correct build order
```

Remove cache_from and image as so:

```
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      target: sylius_nginx
    depends_on:
      - php
      - nodejs
```

Do the same for the php: and the nodejs.